# How to retrieve deleted text messages from iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone, messages, data-recovery

I need to be able to retrieve some deleted text messages from my Daughters phone which were deleted approx. 1 week ago.

I have had limited success by using an online service called TeenSafe which has pulled some of the messages back, but these appear to be mostly my daughters side of the conversation with only sporadic responses from the other party.

What I would like to know is how TeenSafe is managing to retrieve some of these deleted messages, and if it can retrieve some, is there a way that I can use a similar method to get the rest of them back?

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-restore-deleted-text-messages-on-an-iphone/3/

Answer (score 1):

If the iPhone was backed up to a computer through iTunes, you can explore the contents of the backup with a tool like this: http://supercrazyawesome.com if there's no backup then it becomes a lot more difficult as they're removed from the message database.